# Preventing fragment from reloading on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What i am having**:: A single list fragment attached to a activity

---

**What i am trying to achieve**:: I want to prevent the fragment from reloading when i rotate the screen

---

**What i have done so far**:: I did some r/d on stackoverflow and found out i have to use           `setRetainInstance(true);` in order to prevent the fragment from reloading itself on orientation change of the screen

---

**Question**::

- Even if i have used          `setRetainInstance(true);` when i used the
  orientation change the screen reloades the fragment
- Where i am doing wrong
- What are the ways to achieve my goal
- How can i correct my code below

---

**mFragSortingHome.java**

```
public class mFragSortingHome extends SherlockListFragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Button ratingButtonId,priceButtonId,distanceButtonId;
    String queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListBuffet=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        //Setting the NavigationTag from AppControllerApplication class
        AppController.CURRENT_FRAGMENT="mFragSortingHome";

        setRetainInstance(true);

        return view;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
                WillYouQuitAppDialog();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void WillYouQuitAppDialog(){
        //GPS-Dialog
        WillYouQuitAppDialog quitAlert;
        try {
            quitAlert = new WillYouQuitAppDialog();
            quitAlert.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "GpsAlert_Tag");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ratingButtonId=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ratingButtonId);
        priceButtonId=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.priceButtonId);
        distanceButtonId=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.distanceButtonId);

        ratingButtonId.setOnTouchListener(this);
        priceButtonId.setOnTouchListener(this);
        distanceButtonId.setOnTouchListener(this);

        //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragRatingAscendingListTag"), "FragRatingAscendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);
        priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
        distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);

        CharSequence styledItemName1,styledItemName2,styledItemName3;

        styledItemName1=setMultiStylingSpan("(ASC)",new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00aeef")));
        styledItemName1=TextUtils.concat(ratingButtonId.getText()+"\n",setMultiStylingSpan(styledItemName1,new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f)));
        ratingButtonId.setText(styledItemName1);

        styledItemName2=setMultiStylingSpan("(DESC)",new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00aeef")));
        styledItemName2=TextUtils.concat(priceButtonId.getText()+"\n",setMultiStylingSpan(styledItemName2,new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f)));
        priceButtonId.setText(styledItemName2);

        styledItemName3=setMultiStylingSpan("(DESC)",new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00aeef")));
        styledItemName3=TextUtils.concat(distanceButtonId.getText()+"\n",setMultiStylingSpan(styledItemName3,new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f)));
        distanceButtonId.setText(styledItemName3);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        new LoadNextPage().execute();
        /*FragmentAdapter adapter=new FragmentAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.display_buffet_adapater, arrayListBuffet);
        setListAdapter(adapter);*/
    }


    protected class LoadNextPage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg0){
            //// dA=new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());


            DatabaseHandler mHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);


            HashMap<String, String> mapObj;
///
            try {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        mapObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        mapObj.put("buf_off_id", cursor.getString(1));
                        mapObj.put("from_time", cursor.getString(2));
                        mapObj.put("to_time", cursor.getString(3));
                        mapObj.put("online_price", cursor.getString(4));
                        mapObj.put("reserved_price", cursor.getString(5));
                        mapObj.put("buf_image", cursor.getString(6));
                        mapObj.put("res_name", cursor.getString(7));
                        mapObj.put("rating", cursor.getString(8));
                        mapObj.put("latitude", cursor.getString(9));
                        mapObj.put("longitude", cursor.getString(10));
                        mapObj.put("buf_type_name", cursor.getString(11));
                        mapObj.put("from_date", cursor.getString(12));
                        mapObj.put("to_date", cursor.getString(13));
                        mapObj.put("city_id", cursor.getString(14));
                        mapObj.put("city_name", cursor.getString(15));
                        mapObj.put("meal_type_id", cursor.getString(16));
                        mapObj.put("meal_type_name", cursor.getString(17));
                        mapObj.put("distance", cursor.getString(18));
                        mapObj.put("buf_desc", cursor.getString(19));
                        Log.d("<-->MapObject<-->", mapObj.toString());
                        arrayListBuffet.add(mapObj);//Add to arraylist onject(One row i each iteration)
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                db.close();
            }
            //cursor.close();
            Log.d("<-->ArrayListObject<-->", arrayListBuffet.toString());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer offset){
            FragmentAdapter adapter=new FragmentAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.display_buffet_adapater, arrayListBuffet);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }



    //Detecting onTouch for the tabButtons
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v.getId()==R.id.ratingButtonId)
        {
            ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);
            priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            switch (event.getAction())
            {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            {
                ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_focus);

                //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpressed);
                if(AppController.RATING_LIST_FLAG==false){
                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragRatingDescendingListTag"), "FragRatingDescendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating DESC";
                    AppController.RATING_LIST_FLAG=true;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }else{
                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragRatingAscendingListTag"), "FragRatingAscendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY rating ASC";
                    AppController.RATING_LIST_FLAG=false;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            {
                ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            }
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.priceButtonId){
            ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);
            distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            {
                priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_focus);

                //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpressed);
                if(AppController.PRICE_LIST_FLAG==false){
                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragPriceAscendingListTag"), "FragPriceAscendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY online_price ASC";
                    AppController.PRICE_LIST_FLAG=true;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }else{
                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragPriceDescendingListTag"), "FragPriceDescendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY online_price DESC";
                    AppController.PRICE_LIST_FLAG=false;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            {
                priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);

                //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonnormal);

                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            }
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.distanceButtonId) {
            ratingButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            priceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_default);
            distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            {

                distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_focus);
                //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpressed);
                if(AppController.DISTANCE_LIST_FLAG==false){
                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragDistanceAscendingListTag"), "FragDistanceAscendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY distance ASC";
                    AppController.DISTANCE_LIST_FLAG=true;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }else{

                    //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sortBodyContainerId, FragSortParentViewAsList.newInstance("FragDistanceDescendingListTag"), "FragDistanceDescendingListTag").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    queryString="SELECT * FROM buffets ORDER BY distance DESC";
                    AppController.DISTANCE_LIST_FLAG=false;
                    arrayListBuffet.clear();
                    new LoadNextPage().execute();
                }
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            {
                distanceButtonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_button_pressed);
                v.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            }
        }


        return false;
    }

    public static CharSequence setMultiStylingSpan(CharSequence text, CharacterStyle... cs){
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        for (CharacterStyle c : cs){
            ssb.setSpan(c, 0, text.length(), 0);
        }
        text = ssb;
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance). _onCreateView_ still will be called.

Comment: @ Mattia Franchetto ...So whatever the conditions i use i can't prevent the oncreateview from firing ? .... what abt setretainInstancestate & android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" ...what r their purpose then ?

Comment: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) may help. It works by setting the _configChanges_ attribute in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is ..go to your ANdroid Manifest file and put the following code inside the  span

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```